# Why would integrating acceleration give the following solution?

Tags: calculus, integration, optimization, physics, calculus-of-variations

Suppose I have a mass with equation of motion described by:

$x^{''}(t) = F(t) - 1$, $0<t<T$, all initial conditions equal to zero

$F(t)$ is some unknown force

My text claims that the equation of the position of the object is

$x(t) = \int_0^t (t-\tau) F(\tau) d\tau - t^2/2$

Does anyone see how the first term of this solution was derived?

Comment: you must integrate two times

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner: So are you agreeing with the text or disagreeing?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner No, it's correct as is. Just differentiate twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating once (using $x'(0)=0$), from zero to $\tau$, we have
$$
x'(\tau)=\int_0^\tau F(s)\,ds-\tau.
$$
Integrating once more (using $x(0)=0$), from zero to $t$, we find
$$
x(t)=\int_0^t \int_0^\tau F(s)\,ds\,d\tau-t^2/2.
$$
In the integral, we integrate by parts,
$$
\int_0^t 1 \int_0^\tau F(s)\,ds\,d\tau=\Bigl[(\tau-t)\int_0^\tau F(s)\,ds\Bigr]_0^t-\int_0^t (\tau-t)F(\tau)\,d\tau=\int_0^t(t-\tau)F(\tau)\,d\tau.
$$
In the last step, the expression inside brackets are zero.

Comment: Interesting application of integration by parts

Comment: I've heard that integration by parts is the analyst's third lethal weapon.

Comment: @mickep But integration by part can't give you the $\tau - t$ term...how did you derive that given $dv = 1 d\tau$, $u = \int_0^\tau F(s) ds$

Comment: @FemaleTank $t$ is just a constant here, so if (with your notation) $v=\tau-t$, then $dv=1d\tau$.

Comment: @mickep Oooooh, I see, never integrated a constant using integration by parts before, didn't know there was a trick here